# php.ini extension not working

Tags: php, macos, joomla

I deployed Joomla website for my company (This Joomla website was developed by third-party) and they give me an install instruction, just add 3 ext and declare extension_dir, I have done exactly, but seem error still happen ?

And one more thing they require PHP 5.2, and my current install is PHP 5.6, is that cause error ?

I restarted XAMPP any changes I did.

I'm on MAC 10.9, XAMPP 1.8.1

**PHP.ini**

```
 Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; extension_dir = "./"
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext" 
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64"

extension=  "x4_property.so"
extension=  "x4_project.so"
extension=  "unison.so"
```

**My error in log file:**

```
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 395
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 404
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 409
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 395
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 404
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 409
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 395
[16-Jun-2014 08:59:12 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: controller in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/joomla/includes/router.php on line 404
```

Comment: What version of Joomla is this site using? I sincerely hope it's not 3.3

Comment: Does not look like something that adding extensions should solve, just bad code (not checking for presence of array keys before trying to access in this case) - check the affected rows in router.php

Comment: There are some things deprecated in 5.6, that might get you in trouble, but your error log does not indicate this.

Comment: I go to this page (http://www.whitefirdesign.com/resources/check-what-version-of-joomla-you-are-running.html) to check my website version and result is 1.5.x.

Comment: For example in router.php, error happen in this line (line 395):
else if ( $query['option'] == 'com_u_re' && $query['controller'] == 'properties' && isset($query['alias']))

Comment: This isn't a new website is it? Because Joomla 1.5 is way out of date, the last version 1.5.26 was released in March 2012 and has a serious security issue. http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_version_history

Comment: Joomla 1.5 can only run on php 5.3 with a lot of work, I really can predict that 5.6 is going to be very problematic. Remember it also supports php 4.4.7 or something like that.

Comment: Do not pay the third party company. It's embarassing they gave you a 1.5 website. Also, I checked 1.5.26, and the lines are different, if you can't do otherwise update to 1.5.26 and apply the security patches, or 1.5.999, but please consider migrating to 3.3. This will also solve your php compatibility problems